# Git push to branch main. return repository not found. But I was able to pull changes and even resolves conflict

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone, git-pull, git-repo

I have a project already on GitHub organization. I cloned the project and implemented some code, but when I try to push the project back to GitHub, it returns repository not found. But funny enough is that I can pull changes or any update from the branch and resolves some conflict, but when I try to push my changes it still return repository not found.

Below is the error I got from git command:

```
    Validating found git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Using git 2.33.0.windows.2 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
> git rev-parse --git-dir
Open repository: c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b
> git status -z -u
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/auth.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\auth.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\auth.js
> git status -z -u
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/auth.js
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/styles.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\styles.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%
> git remote --verbose
Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git show --textconv :src/components/navbar/navbar.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\navbar\navbar.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git show --textconv :src/components/navbar/TopNavbar
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\navbar\TopNavbar
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git status -z -u
> git show --textconv :src/components/TopNavber/TopNavbar
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\TopNavber\TopNavbar
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git show --textconv :src/components/TopNavbar/TopNavbar.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\TopNavbar\TopNavbar.js
> git cat-file -s c29d20801efece2c29e2a83d068bed301c84ef51
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git show --textconv :src/components/TopNavbar/TopNavbar.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\TopNavbar\TopNavbar.js
> git cat-file -s c29d20801efece2c29e2a83d068bed301c84ef51
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/auth.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\auth.js
> git cat-file -s 696e130c8330521d1a01cb272be8a5e8cdf8a4f4
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/styles.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\styles.js
> git cat-file -s 16a0042be49815829f243a48ff509ebcf863b852
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git add -A -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\App.js C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\styles.js
> git cat-file -s 16a0042be49815829f243a48ff509ebcf863b852
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/styles.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git config --get commit.template
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\styles.js
> git cat-file -s 16a0042be49815829f243a48ff509ebcf863b852
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/styles.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git push origin main:main
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MJTechNG/i-next.git/' not found
> git show --textconv :src/App.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\App.js
> git cat-file -s f31f8d4a1d70cfc81862da68103cedebeb64ed74
> git show --textconv :src/mystoryslams/NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git cat-file -s 07b7366fd4f5f474afac6de95f532d3782f66a85
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git add -A -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\package.json C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\styles.js C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\yarn.lock
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git cat-file -s b4d6f9d9a38c161b4fc098eae0e250b0e053198b
> git show --textconv :src/mystoryslams/NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git log --oneline --cherry main...main@{upstream} --
> git pull --tags origin main
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git cat-file -s b4d6f9d9a38c161b4fc098eae0e250b0e053198b
> git show --textconv :src/mystoryslams/NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git cat-file -s b4d6f9d9a38c161b4fc098eae0e250b0e053198b
> git show --textconv :src/mystoryslams/NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
From https://github.com/MJTechNG/i-next
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
> git push origin main:main
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git cat-file -s b4d6f9d9a38c161b4fc098eae0e250b0e053198b
> git show --textconv :src/mystoryslams/NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git cat-file -s b4d6f9d9a38c161b4fc098eae0e250b0e053198b
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git cat-file -s b4d6f9d9a38c161b4fc098eae0e250b0e053198b
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MJTechNG/i-next.git/' not found
> git show --textconv :src/mystoryslams/NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git status -z -u
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git cat-file -s b4d6f9d9a38c161b4fc098eae0e250b0e053198b
> git show --textconv :src/mystoryslams/NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%B -z -n21 -- c:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git show --textconv :src/home/homeStyles.css
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\home\homeStyles.css
> git cat-file -s 808c9e24bd4a04b7375b212204a1d08e3aa86e1b
> git status -z -u
> git show --textconv :src/mystoryslams/NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\mystoryslams\NYStorySlamCreateAccount.js
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git cat-file -s b4d6f9d9a38c161b4fc098eae0e250b0e053198b
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/auth.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\auth.js
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git cat-file -s 696e130c8330521d1a01cb272be8a5e8cdf8a4f4
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\auth.js
> git cat-file -s 696e130c8330521d1a01cb272be8a5e8cdf8a4f4
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/auth.js
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/styles.js
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\styles.js
> git cat-file -s 82da18df68149a930fad0caf02c30af0d4147e73
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\AhmadTech\Desktop\project-b\src\components\Auth\styles.js
> git config --get commit.template
> git cat-file -s 82da18df68149a930fad0caf02c30af0d4147e73
> git config --get commit.template
> git show --textconv :src/components/Auth/styles.js
> git push origin main:main
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MJTechNG/i-next.git/' not found
```

Comment: The output you show here is not from *a* Git command, it's from *many* Git commands. Some of them worked and some of them failed. The ones that failed are those that tried to use `i-next.git` from `https://github.com/MJTechNG/`, and that fails because https://github.com/MJTechNG/ has no `i-next.git` (you can see this by going to that URL in your browser).

Comment: (There's one other failure shown, having to do with unmerged files, but there's nothing obvious above it to show where the unmerged files came from.)